# bash - showing usage/help on no arguments with shflags

Tags: bash, arguments

Let's say this is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# source shflags
. shflags

# define a 'name' command-line string flag
DEFINE_string 'name' 'world' 'name to say hello to' 'n'

# parse the command-line
FLAGS "$@" || exit $?
eval set -- "${FLAGS_ARGV}"

# say Hello!
echo "Hello, ${FLAGS_name}!"
```

For using --help (or -h) I can see the usage/help:

```
USAGE: ./sample.sh [flags] args
flags:
  -n,--name:  name to say hello to (default: 'world')
  -h,--[no]help:  show this help (default: false)
```

However I'd like to display the same usage/help (shflags constructed) also in case of no arguments provided to script.
Any idea how can I do so?

I've tried adding:

```
if [ $# == 0 ] ; then
    echo $USAGE
    exit 1;
fi
```

Well, the detection of no args works, but I have nothing printed.

**UPDATE**:

shflags version refered is available on: http://code.google.com/p/shflags/source/browse/tags/1.0.3/src/shflags

Comment: Where did you define `$USAGE`, and where did you put the added code?

Comment: well, that's the problem, that I didn't define it anywhere (I've just seen it somewhere used with shflags I guess) :) and where did I put it? at the very end. I guess my try is irrelevant in searching for solution. Still I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: Show the content of `shflags`, at least the part that shows the help message.

Comment: see the update for shflags contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, got it, following does the job for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

# source shflags
. shflags

# define a 'name' command-line string flag
DEFINE_string 'name' 'world' 'name to say hello to' 'n'

# parse the command-line
FLAGS "$@" || exit $?
if [ $# == 0 ] ; then
    flags_help
    exit 1;
fi
eval set -- "${FLAGS_ARGV}"

# say Hello!
echo "Hello, ${FLAGS_name}!"
```

Thanks to @Ansgar.Wiechers who pointed me the right direction when asking for the source of the shflags :) I found it there myself :)

So the function of interest is:

```
flags_help
```